# Local Storage not saving data when using DNS but saving when using IP

Tags: javascript, local-storage

**When logging using IP -** We save some data related to logged in user in the local storage of browser. If in any case the stored data is not found in the local storage we forcefully logout the user. In case when we are using IP the data persist in the local storage hence whenever the page is refreshed it does not redirect to logout page.

**When logging using DNS  -** In case when we are logging using DNS nothing is stored in the local storage of browser. So whenever we refresh the page, it checks whether the data is stored or not. If not it forcefully logout the user.

[When using IP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JXL0H.png)

[image]

[When using DNS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cWhk3.png)

[image]

Comment: Could it be that when you are using the IP you are using port 8080, using the domain name you are using port 80?

Comment: In your DNS image, why did you hide the fact that you actually have storage for `http://139.59.59.229:8080` when you load the FQDN?

Answer (score 0):

When you go to the site using FQDN, your site serves the following

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>

<head>
  <title>hr.visioneering.in</title>

</head>
<frameset rows="100%,*" border="0">
  <frame src="http://139.59.59.229:8080/HR" frameborder="0" />
  <frame frameborder="0" noresize />
</frameset>

<!-- pageok -->
<!-- 12 -->
<!-- -->
</html>
```

When you go to the IP address / port you get a web page that does not use [deprecated - see docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/frameset) frameset

So, in the FQDN case the web page you are interacting with is still the IP address:8080 site and that is where storage is held

so - in your question where you say `When logging using DNS` - you are mistaken, because you don't ever actually log in using DNS